# Error while reading the file in HDFS from Java

Tags: java, maven, hadoop

I was trying to read a file from HDFS in my Java program. I was getting error in the path.

```
Cannot instantiate the type Path
```

Here is the code:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.*;

try{
    Path pt = new Path("hdfs://npvm11.np.wc1.yellowpages.com:9000/user/john/abc.txt");
    FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(new Configuration());
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fs.open((org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path) pt)));
    String line;
    line=br.readLine();
    while (line != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
        line = br.readLine();
    }
} catch(Exception e) {
}
```

My pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-hdfs</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0-cdh4.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-auth</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0-cdh4.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0-cdh4.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.0.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Please check the below thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33872904/is-there-any-existing-api-to-read-and-write-to-hdfs-from-java/33876096#33876096